# Creating a modeless dialog box that appears automatically after 5 mins

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, dialog

I have a sharepoint site. On it I want to apply `modeless dialog box` , that will appear after 5 mins when user has open the site.

Please suggest. I have written javascript code in CEWP that opens a modeless dialog box on button click.

How to open that dialog box automatically after 5 mins?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the javascript function `setTimeout()` to do that

```
setTimeout(ModalDialogJavascriptGoesHere, 300000);
```

First parameter is the javascript you want to execute. The second parameter is milliseconds you want to pass before the javascript is executed.

5 minutes is 300000 milliseconds.

```
Minutes * 60 * 1000
```

---

**Update**
To make the dialog disappear automatically after a certain amount of time, you'll have to use the same logic as before; using the `setTimeout()` javascript function.

Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK), 5000);
</script>
```

You'll have to add the above javascript to the page you are opening in the modal dialog.

Comment: What will be the way to show the opened dialog box only for 5 sec and then it will vanish automatically.

Comment: @user44135 Please check my updated answer.